# SQL Server 2012 Public Server role

Tags: sql-server

I have a login "user2" who is assigned to "Public" server role. Does this mean the login will not be able to access any database? The weird part is that, the login is able to access 3 out of 9 databases on the server. I'm not sure if there's some setting on the database which I need to change or is it the public role I need to look into. Any help and explanation would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should study what a `user` is, take a look here; [How to: Create a Database User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545(v=sql.105).aspx)

Server role has nothing to do with database access, and any newly created login is a member of `public` server role.

If your user access 3 of 9 databases, it means it is mapped to these databases (i.e. has a correspondent user in these databases, or the `guest` user is enabled, so anyone can access this database (for example, `guest` user as enabled in master database)